# regexp doesn't proper test

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex:

```
/^([\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z]+['-]{0,1}){3,30}$/
```

Which means I can use 3-30 given characters, but my upper limit doesn't work. Here is the example with 35 characters string:

```
/^([\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z]+['-]{0,1}){3,30}$/.test('TXTGWDRWHWTXTGSXYEWGUAHZXQCWDRWHWTX');
```

And it returns true, but should returns false

Comment: So you want the total length to be from 3-30 characters with an optional quote or dash at the end ?

Comment: The regex has nested quantifiers; the `+` gives the inner subpattern an unlimited length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of these *length* questions are different.
No two are alike.

For this one I'd suggest

`/^[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z]{2,29}[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'-]$/.test('TXTGWDRWHWTXTGSXYEWGUAHZXQCWDRWHWTX');`

Which, gives a total of 3-30 characters.

```js
console.log( /^[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z]{2,29}[\u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'-]$/.test('TXTGWDRWHWTXTGSXYEWGUAHZXQCWDRWHWTX') );
```

Output

```
false
```